# IE changes the title value, if there is a # present in the URL

Tags: html, internet-explorer, title, page-title

If a '#' value is present in the URL, Internet explorer replaces the title text with the URL

Steps to Reproduce:

1. In Internet Explorer, Go www.store.apple.com/us, have a look the title, it will say "Welcome to the Apple Store - Apple Store(U.S)"
2. Append '#123' to the URL, so the new URL should will now be, http://www.store.apple.com/us#123
3. See the value in the Title Bar, it will be 'http://www.store.apple.com/us#123'

Is there a way to overcome this apart from stripping it with Javascript and will it affect Search Engine Rank?

P.S: The apple.com is used just for example purpose, this bug holds good for any website.

Answer (score 0):

What version of IE are you using?

I tried with IE8, and the window title changes to show the URL, however the title shown in the tab is still the title specified in the <title> tag of the page.

What is displayed in IE won't have any effect on search engine ranking.

Comment: I don't know why IE does this. It's not actually changing the title of the page, so it won't have any effect on search engine results. It's just displaying strangely.